# Android Stick Buttons in bottom of the navigation drawer

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, navigation-drawer

i want to stick or attach the two buttons to the bottom of the navigation drawer.
i fail to attach buttons to the bottom which  appear always to the bottom of the navigation drawer
i tried layout_weight but it did't respond well.
my code is given below.
i describe it in below figure
please help me.thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/setting_background" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/exp_background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/news_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@color/news_list_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/news_list_divider_height" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newlist_relative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/setting_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/newslist_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight=".95"
        android:background="@color/setting_background"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newslist_drawer"
        android:layout_weight=".05" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newslist_done"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="  Done  "
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newslist_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:text="  Cancel  " />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/exp_background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/news_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@color/news_list_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/news_list_divider_height" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newlist_relative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/setting_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/newslist_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight=".95"
        android:background="@color/setting_background"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newslist_drawer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom
        android:layout_weight=".05" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newslist_done"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="  Done  "
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newslist_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:text="  Cancel  " />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try it out say dude. Happy coding :)

Comment: by the way tanks for suggestion.but how can i put  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in linearlayout which parent is also linearlayout. does it work in linearlayout?

Comment: Just take out from that layout and place it as seperate inside Relative layout, then it works. try it out , nd say dude.